# How to bring a google drive to my web application?

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive-api

My company have uploaded data to Google Drive then we want to make application from Google Drive API and bring this app to our website. We have had different teams in my website.

Can we set permission via Google Drive API for this teams (store in my database) to access to the folder into Google Drive application ?

Answer (score 0):

In order to insert a permission, each permission holder should be a Google user, group or a domain. If you can represent your pseudo teams in terms of one of them, you can do.

Permission inserting method signature is available on https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/insert, we require you to give us an email (user or group) or a domain in order to identify your principal.